# Access variable outside foreach loop

Tags: php, html, foreach

EDIT: Solved by adding modal inside loop

Can someone explain to me how to access the `foreach` loop variable outside `foreach`?

```
<?php foreach($sup as $data){ ?>
  <tr>
  <td><i class="circular blue lock icon"></i><?php echo $data['id']; ?></td>
  <td><div class="ui large green label">
              Solved!
  </div></td>
  <td><?php echo $data['subject']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data['text']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data['date']; ?></td>
   <td>
       <div class="ui buttons">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" />
          <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Lock" class="ui button" tabindex="5">
          <div class="or"></div>
          <button id="sup" class="ui right labeled icon positive button">
                  Reply
          </button>
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

For example, I want to use `$data['text']` in my modal.

Comment: When and how you are loading the modal??

Comment: In same file as this code. Modal is loading by press button in code above

Comment: @milfman How does that button invoke a modal?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton by $_POST superglobal  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...

Comment: from what I understand what you wanna do (showing dynamic content in a modal)- it would be best to solve that in javascript.

Comment: and to answer your question: you cannot access it from outside. But you can pass it to a (js?) function.

Answer (score 0):

Add the data attribute to your button:

```
<button data-text="<?php echo $data['text']; ?>" class="ui right labeled icon positive button">
```

Then, in your modal you can access it with Javascript, like so:

```
var text = document.getElementById('sup').dataset.text
```

Also, you can't use an unique id inside a foreach loop, otherwise it will be replicated along with the rest of the code. Remove the "id" field from your button.

Comment: you will have to make the button id unique to make that work. no he'll have several buttons with that id